# which class should i import to use jboss cache?

Tags: java

i want to use jboss cache, but i don't know which jar and where to get it.

```
      import org.jboss.cache.Fqn;
      import org.jboss.cache.Node;
      import org.jboss.cache.PropertyConfigurator;
      import org.jboss.cache.TreeCache;
```

i get errors like "The import org.jboss.cache.TreeCache cannnot be resolved."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All JBoss Cache artifacts are available [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossCacheDownloadsPage).

[JBoss Cache](http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache) is no longer developed. Consider using its successor [infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan).